# How to make dynamic url with multiple vars like in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How to make dynamic url with multiple vars like in Laravel in my own small MVC? Like when I write `Route::get('/post/$1/$2', 'PostsController@showUserPosts')`. How do you approach this?

Comment: Route::get('/post/{var_a}/{var_b}', 'PostsController@showUserPosts'). then in thefunction showUserPosts($var_a,$var_b) and so on

Comment: Read the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Define a route with parameters:

```
Route::get('posts/{post_id}/{user_id}', 'PostsController@showUserPosts')->name('user-posts');
```

And in view:

```
<a href="{{ route('user-posts', ['user_id'=> 1, 'post_id' => 1]) }}">link</a>
```

For more info check
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters